# IntersectionObserver: update rootMargin / two intersectionObservers on page

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Is it possible to update rootMargin depends on element is currently intersecting ?

On page I have 3 elements to observe and want to set different rootMargin value for second element

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: "0px 0px -12% 0px",
  threshold: 0.5,
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.target.className === "main__image__above__wrapper") {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        scrollMainImage.style.left = "0px";
        scrollMainImage.style.opacity = "1";
      }
    } else if (entry.target.className === "main__image__box") {
      options = {
        rootMargin: "0px 0px -40% 0px",
        threshold: 0.5, 
      };
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        scrollBoxDay.classList.add("zeroOpacity");
      } else {
        scrollBoxDay.classList.remove("zeroOpacity");
      }
    } else if (entry.target.className === "main__image__estate__wrapper") {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        photoEstate.style.left = "0px";
        photoEstate.style.opacity = "1";
      }
    }
  });
}, options);

observer.observe(scrollMainImageWrapper);
observer.observe(scrollBoxWrapper);
observer.observe(photoEstateWrapper);
```

Searching throught web I found that rootMargin is readOnly value.

So if it's not possible to change dynamically rootMargin values or is it a good practice to have 2 intersection observers on page ?